# Get value from store or store and get if not exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what I want to achieve is a way to **get previously generated or generate, store and return data**, in a way, which could be used as function - needed to join or APPLY in UPDATE scripts.

So, having data generate function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION generateData()
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'asdyukyuk' --some rng related algorithm
END
```

And "get or generate, save and get" procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE getOrGenerateAndGet (@orig NVARCHAR(20), @result NVARCHAR(20) OUTPUT)
    AS
        BEGIN
            IF @orig IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @result = NULL
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @hash VARBINARY(64) = dbo.getHash(@orig)
                    SELECT @result = GENERATED_DATA FROM STORED_DATA WHERE HASH = @hash
                    IF @result IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            SET @result = dbo.generateData()
                            INSERT INTO STORED_DATA (HASH, GENERATED_DATA) VALUES (@hash, @result)
                        END
                END
        RETURN 1
        END;
    GO
```

And UPDATE script:

```
UPDATE FRAGILE_DATA SET FRAGILE_COLUMN = getOrGenerateAndGet(FRAGILE_COLUMN)
```

it's obviously not working, because getOrGenerateAndGet is not function.

However, with function way:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION getOrGenerateAndGet (@orig NVARCHAR(20))
        RETURNS NVARCHAR(20)
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(20)
            IF @orig IS NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @result = NULL
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @hash VARBINARY(64) = dbo.getHash(@orig)
                    SELECT @result = GENERATED_DATA FROM STORED_DATA WHERE HASH = @hash
                    IF @result IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT @result = dbo.generateData()
                            EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO STORED_DATA (HASH, GENERATED_DATA) VALUES (@hash, @result)'
                        END
                END
            RETURN @result
        END;
    GO
```

it's still not working, because "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

Is there any way to achieve this, without enabling sql command shell?

Comment: Not with a TSQL function. You may well be able to do it with a CLR function though.

Comment: why don't you `return an output` over a `stored procedure` and execute update with that value... in short you will have two lines ... 1st stored proc with output and 2nd the update statement